# Why does arp request get broadcast even though it knows the ip address of receiver?

Tags: ip, ipv4, arp

Since the arp request wants to know the Mac address of an ip address which belongs to any one device what's the purpose of sending a broadcast Anyway even though we know only that ip address device will respond? Can't it unicast to the receiver ip directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chicken meet Egg

Ethernet can't "send something to an IP address", it can only send something to a MAC address. The whole point of ARP is to convert the IP address of the next hop (which may or may not be the destination) into a MAC address so we can send the packet.

Comment: So if I send a broadcast, is it still using only layer 2 and not layer 3? Does all broadcast happen in layer 2? I'm starting to study networking, pardon the confusions.

Comment: @Nateshbhat ARP uses a layer-2 broadcast - it's not using an IP packet, so there's no IP destination address. Usually, a layer-3 broadcast uses a layer-2 broadcast for delivery.